# Smoothing output events in Stream Analytics

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

I have a stream analytics job which processes a fair few records and does a combination of rolling and sliding windows. I take my input events and do a rolling one minute window on them and then use that as the input to a one-hour sliding window. This allows me to keep an average from the last hour without having to maintain too much event state in stream analytics.

The result of this is that every minute, on the minute, I output a large number of events. My CosmosDB, which is receiving the updates, has an extremely spiky load as a result. For 59 seconds it is almost idle and for one second it is overloaded. Is there any way to smear the output events over the entire minute and balance out the load?

Answer (score 0):

While Azure Stream Analytics backs off based on error codes returned by cosmosdb, there is no way to directly limit the rate at which ASA writes. If you have a usecase, please consider adding it as a feature request here, https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270577-stream-analytics.